# Moving to the UK with an image scanner and cash

Tags: uk, legal

I'll move to the UK very soon, and I intend to bring my image scanner with me, as well as some cash (£2000). Do you think I'll regret this decision once I arrive there? I am from an EEA country with a certain reputation for tax evasion/money laundering, and would like to avoid getting detained at the airport. (I should like to emphasise that I am not involved in any form of criminal activity, I use my scanner to scan my documents and not to scan bank notes) Has any of you ever brought your image scanner with you? Could this be a problem? Is it even legal to bring an image scanner with me? I won't bring a printer, though.

Comment: I don't see what would be wrong with a scanner? And 2k pounds are well within limits of what you can bring

Comment: Most phone camera have better quality then image scanner (on colour).

Comment: @HankyPanky think of counterfeits

Comment: But why do you have to think about those?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to an ordinary flat-bed scanner...

[image]

**No**, nobody cares if you bring it with you into the country. Scanners of any variety are sold at any electronics store. Likewise 2000 GBP is a small sum that can be less than the cost of a flight ticket, depending on where you're coming from. Relax and enjoy your stay.